# WASAPI AudioClient.GetMixFormat() returns AUDCLNT_E_NOT_INITIALIZED

Tags: wasapi

I'm attempting to use AudioClient interface for the first time, without luck.
So far I managed to get the default AudioClient interface using the successfully MMDeviceEnumerator and MMDevice interfaces:

```
CoCreateInstance(
       CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, nil,
       CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
       MMEnumerator);
MMEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender,eConsole,MMDevice);
MMDevice.Activate(IID_IAudioClient, CLSCTX_ALL, nil, AudioClient);
```

(Result checking code not included here). This 3 call all returned no errors, and I've got a non-nil interface ptr in AudioClient variable.
My problem is when I try to get the mixing waveformat:

```
AudioClient.GetMixFormat(pwfx)
```

This returns the code 0x88890001 which is AUDCLNT_E_NOT_INITIALIZED. -> Of course not initialized as I only wanted to get what waveformat it likes first.

Looking up msdn tells that the AudioClient.GetMixFormat can be called before AudioClient.Initialization. Also the AUDCLNT_E_NOT_INITIALIZED is not on the list of possible return values. So I'm confused about what did I do wrong. GetMixFormat() doc -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370872(v=vs.85).aspx

Another weird thing is that when I call AudioClient.GetStreamLatency() it returns with S_OK and with a quasi-random value around 1000ms. But the documentation states that "This method requires prior initialization of the IAudioClient interface. All calls to this method will fail with the error AUDCLNT_E_NOT_INITIALIZED until the client initializes the audio stream by successfully calling the". Therefore I think I have a working AudioClient interface, I just can't understand why it doesn't work as the way documentation says.

(I'm using win7 64bit, Sound Blaster Live 5.1 with kx-project driver (DSound and classic windows MM sound works ok, but with a 100ms terrible long latency,  that's the only reason why I'm going to use WASAPI on the win7)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've forgot to tell one important thing: I used the MFPACK https://code.google.com/p/mfpack-media-foundation/source/browse/trunk/MFPACK/CoreAudio/WASAPI?r=131 library. And it has some errors in it: In the IAudioClient interface it contains the methods in alphabetical order, and not in the order which is was designed by Microsoft. After I corrected this, everything works fine.

Comment: `GetMixFormat` is designed to work before `Initialize` call. The problem might be related to hardware driver or specific hook you have installed in the system.

Comment: Also getting this error. Seems related to Delphi (or possibly the MFPack), since it works fine in (MS) C++.

Answer (score 3):

I actually found the bug. The definition of `IAudioClient` in **MFPack** is incorrect, the interface functions are in the wrong order. (I'd like to push this in some way some day, if I find the time for it, move to git etc.)
This is the correct ordering of methods in IAudioClient:

```
IAudioClient = interface(IUnknown)
['{1CB9AD4C-DBFA-4c32-B178-C2F568A703B2}']
    function Initialize(ShareMode: AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE; StreamFlags: Dword; hnsBufferDuration: REFERENCE_TIME; hnsPeriodicity: REFERENCE_TIME; pFormat: PWaveFormatEx; AudioSessionGuid: LPCGUID): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetBufferSize(out pNumBufferFrames: UINT32): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetStreamLatency(out phnsLatency: REFERENCE_TIME): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetCurrentPadding(out pNumPaddingFrames: UINT32): HResult; stdcall;
    function IsFormatSupported(ShareMode: AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE; pFormat: PWaveFormatEx; out ppClosestMatch: PWaveFormatEx): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetMixFormat(out ppDeviceFormat: PWaveFormatEx): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetDevicePeriod(out phnsDefaultDevicePeriod: REFERENCE_TIME; phnsMinimumDevicePeriod: REFERENCE_TIME): HResult; stdcall;
    function Start(): HResult; stdcall;
    function Stop(): HResult; stdcall;
    function Reset(): HResult; stdcall;
    function SetEventHandle(const eventHandle: HANDLE): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetService(const riid: TGUID; out ppv: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
    //The GetService method supports the following service interfaces: IAudioCaptureClient, IAudioClock, IAudioRenderClient,
    //IAudioSessionControl, IAudioStreamVolume, IChannelAudioVolume, IMFTrustedOutput, ISimpleAudioVolume.
    //Since Windows 7 the new interface indentifier IID_IMFTrustedOutput has been added, but is not implemented here.
end;
```

The function ReleaseBuffer is also wrong, this is the correct parameters:

```
IAudioRenderClient = interface(IUnknown)
['{F294ACFC-3146-4483-A7BF-ADDCA7C260E2}']
    function GetBuffer(const NumFramesRequested: UINT; out ppData: PByte): HResult; stdcall;
    function ReleaseBuffer(const NumFramesWritten: UINT32; const dwFlags: DWord): HResult; stdcall;
end;
```